# how I can extends PhotoView

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

hello I would like to do the same thing but with PhotoView concretely I want to draw or write on the picture

thank you for any hint

```
class ImageEditor extends CustomPainter {
   
  ImageEditor({
    this.image,
  });

  ui.Image image;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.scale(0.5,0.5);
    Future<ByteData> data = image.toByteData();
    canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(0.0,0.0), new Paint());
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(300, 240), 300.2,new Paint());

  }
```